# How to display an xhtml file?

Tags: wpf, xhtml, wpf-controls

I have a TreeView that represents a book. Each chapter of the book is in xhtml format (unzipped from epub). The paths of the chapters are stored as Tags of the TreeView items. I need to display a selected chapter upon click on a TreeView element.

Could you please tell what is the best way to display an xhtml document? What control is the best for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) control and then set the Source property to your XHTML file url. If the tag is not pointing to a XHTML file but directly to raw HTML text, you maybe need to create this file as the [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.source.aspx) property is a Uri object.

That is definitely the way to display HTML in WPF.

Comment: Thanks! I just wonder how I can get the tag. private void treeTableOfContents_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e). I see how to get the header (e.NewValue.Header), but not sure about the tag... Can I access it at all? Thanks.

Comment: You have to retrieve it from your TreeView instance: myTreeView.SelectedItem. If you did not named your TreeView instance, or name it or cast the sender object as a TreeView.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has [a demo of how to convert XAML to XHTML and vice-versa.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972129.aspx) This should get you most of the way to where you're going.

Comment: I don't see any project there... I guess I am missing something.